# c++ defining array size with a const variable

Tags: c++, arrays, variables, size

```
int place = determinePlace(input);

const int arraySize = (place + 1);
int decimal[arraySize] = {};
```

Hi!

I tried to use a const int variable to define the array size of decimal[].
However, error C2057 and error C2466 keeps on coming up.

Are there any suggestions?

Comment: For the future, it would be nice if you could include the actual error messages rather than just the error numbers. Those error numbers are compiler specific, and i don't think anyone has them memorized.

Comment: Maybe use a `constexpr`  (but that probably won't work here, unless `determinePlace`  is a `constexpr`  function, and `input` is a `constexpr` also; which is very unlikely)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joachim is right,
you are trying to set:

```
const int arraySize = (determinePlace(input) + 1);
```

this doesn't work, because you are trying to get a user input or something similar which will be only accessible when you run the program not when you compile it.

I would try something like this:

```
#include <vector>

using std::vector;

vector<int> decimal;
decimal.resize(determinePlace(input) +1);
decimal = {};
```

Answer (score 2):

Even if you declare `arraySize` as `const`, it's still not a compile-time constant since it have to be calculated run-time.

Use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead:

```
std::vector<int> decimal(arraySize);
```

Answer (score 1):

array size should be `int` , `unsigned`, `unsigned int` or `size_t` not a decimal type `double`

use `std::vector`

to use

```
#include <vector> // include the header
```

to define a vector

```
std::vector<int> vec = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

this defines vector int with a values of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

to add some values

```
vec.push_back(12);
```

adds 12 to vec vector