# Error in the subscript of the array

Tags: c++, arrays

This is giving me an error that expression `a` must have a constant value. I cannot understand what is wrong with this method. `n` is an integer and I am giving it the array size. Can somebody help me to understand this problem?

```
int fib(int n)
{
const int a = n;
int f[a];
...
}
```

Comment: As it says, it needs to be a _constant_, you’re using a _variable_. C++ doesn’t allow Variable Length Arrays.

Comment: what's `n` right now? Nobody knows, neither does the compiler. `n` isn't constant

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard)

Comment: @ramsingh In C++, you should be using `std::vector<int> f(a);` for this purpose.

Comment: Works fine for me (clang++). What?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c++ defining array size with a const variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31090633/c-defining-array-size-with-a-const-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Others have said this already, but essentially the problem is that you are assigning the array a size that is variable and can only be known at runtime of the program. The compiler has to know what size the array is going to be at compile time, so that's a problem and conflicts with the C++ standard. Notably some compilers do have extensions that support this, so that could be your confusion. I would recommend using `std::vector` instead for anytime you need variable length arrays.